# ruby on rails integration with postgres db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am new to ruby on rails and I am trying to develop some demo application. I am trying to use postgres as database server. I am trying to setup database from rails using `rake db:setup` command. I am getting following exception. I researched using google but I could not figure out the problem with my little knowledge. Could you please help me out with fixing this issue.

Ruby version 2.2.2 and rails version 4.2.1

Following is the exception:

```
$ bin/rake db:setup
/home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:303:in `block in visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias': Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
Unknown alias: default (Psych::BadAlias)
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:303:in `fetch'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:303:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:31:in `accept'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:321:in `block in revive_hash'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `each'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `each_slice'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `revive_hash'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:161:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:31:in `accept'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:321:in `block in revive_hash'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `each'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `each_slice'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:319:in `revive_hash'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:161:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:31:in `accept'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:295:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:31:in `accept'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:37:in `to_ruby'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:246:in `load'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:104:in `database_configuration'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:117:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:316:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:319:in `active_record_configured?'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:251:in `disconnect_database'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:97:in `preload'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/satish/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What does your `database.yml` file look like? The error `Unknown alias: default` means you probably have a line looking like `<<: *default` but no corresponding `&default` reference for it to merge.

Comment: Thank you Robert for your answer. yes there is a small syntax issue in .yml file and i forgot to add gem 'pg'  in Gemfile. i have fixed it and now everything looks fine and i am back on track.. :) Thank you very much once again..